# Event.sinkEvents won't work

Tags: gwt, vaadin7

I have a vaadin 7 client widget which has a DIV element in it. I am trying to register the click event on DIV elment through Event.sinkEvents. however the browser events never get fired. Here is the piece of code

```
public class MyWidget extends Widget{
 private final DivElement popup = Document.get().createDivElement();

public MyWidget() {

initDOM();
initListeners();
}


private void initDOM(){
popup.setClassName(STYLECLASS);
setElement(popup);
}

public void initListeners(){
Event.sinkEvents(popup, Event.ONCLICK|Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
Event.setEventListener(popup, new EventListener() {

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
Window.alert("clicked"); // this never get fired.
event.stopPropagation();
}
});

}
```

Please suggest any pointer.

Regards,
Azhar

Answer (score 0):

There is never a need to do `DOM.setEventListener` in a widget (and in fact it should be avoided) - just override the widget's own onBrowserEvent method after sinking those events. By sinking those events and attaching the widget to a parent, GWT has internally called setEventListener on the widget itself so that it can handle its own events.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Event#sinkEvents`, use `Widget#sinkEvents`. And override the widget's `onBrowseEvent` to handle the events.

This should do it:

```
public class MyWidget extends Widget{
private final DivElement popup = Document.get().createDivElement();

public MyWidget() {
    initDOM();
}


private void initDOM(){
    popup.setClassName(STYLECLASS)
    setElement(popup);
    sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK|Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    if(event.getTypeInt()==Event.ONCLICK){
        Window.alert("Clicked");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Overridding the onBrowserEvent method works.

below code worked.

```
Event.sinkEvents(popup, Event.ONCLICK|Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
```

replaced with

```
sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK|Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
```

Will sink the events on widget and not on any DIV. after that below brower event got fired.

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
Window.alert("clicked"); // this never get fired.
event.stopPropagation();
}
});
```